# Possible to use grep in eshell without opening a *grep* buffer?

Tags: eshell

When i use grep in eshell, like 'cat test.txt | grep test', grep opens it's own buffer with the result. Is it possible to capture the output of grep in the eshell buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eshell, `grep` is a built-in command, which is a lisp function and works like Emacs's `M-x grep`. To use the external `grep` command, you need to use `*grep` instead. If you want to type just `grep` , you can declare an alias, i.e.,

```
~ $ alias grep '*grep $*'
```

The `alias` here is a built-in command as well, unlike shell's, it creates a persistent alias. If you want to cancel this alias, you have to delete corresponding entry from your `eshell-aliases-file` manually. Eshell doesn't provide a `unalias`.

I suggest you consult the Eshell manual, especially [(eshell) Built-ins](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Built_002dins.html).