# How to make grep buffer replace eshell buffer in current window?

Tags: window, display-buffer-alist

When you `grep` in `eshell`, it spawns a `grep` buffer and displays it in a separate window. I'd like to have it simply display in the same `eshell` window (replacing the `eshell` buffer -- same as when you do something like `find-file` vs `find-file-other-window`) so it doesn't mess up one of my other windows (but I'd like to use the Lisp `grep`). Related: [Possible to use grep in eshell without opening a *grep* buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21864/possible-to-use-grep-in-eshell-without-opening-a-grep-buffer)

My attempts here were unsuccessful:

```
;; don't pop windows up without my permission
(setq pop-up-windows nil)

(setq switch-to-buffer-obey-display-actions t)
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("\\*grep\\*.*" display-buffer-reuse-window))
```

`eshell` seems to by default behave like this. I would like that whenever I open a new buffer, it always replaces the current unless I explicitly use an `other-window` command.